# Syntax Error in FROM Clause C# & MS-Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm simple trying to get information from a MS Acces database and put it in some textboxes, but i got the error

> Syntax error in FROM clause

I don't know what im doing wrong and the sql works in Access itself.

```
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT [CharacterID], [CharacterName], [Race], [Class], [Background], [Level], [Alignment], [Experience Points], [PlayerName]
                                FROM Character";

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            Player p = new Player();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                p.CharacterID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                p.CharacterName = reader.GetString(1);
                p.Race = reader.GetString(2);
                p.Class = reader.GetString(3);
                p.Background = reader.GetString(4);
                p.Level = reader.GetInt32(5);
                p.Alignment = reader.GetString(6);
                p.ExperiencePoints = reader.GetInt32(7);
                p.PlayerName = reader.GetString(8);
            }
            characters.Add(p);

            txtCharacterName.Text = p.CharacterName;
            txtClassLevel.Text = p.Class + " " + p.Level.ToString();
            txtBackground.Text = p.Background;
            txtPlayerName.Text = p.PlayerName;
            txtRace.Text = p.Race;
            txtAlignment.Text = p.Alignment;
            txtExperiencePoints.Text = p.ExperiencePoints.ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping `Character` as `[Character]`? I wouldn't be surprised if `Character` were a keyword...

Comment: Character, somewhat unsurprisely, is a reserved word: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ahh, looks like that was it *facepalm*, thx